# AWS server with google maps

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js, google-maps

I am using AWS server for my application. There I'm facing a problem using google maps when i'm using `localhost` to run my application google maps does work fine but when I'm using IP address to run the application, it's not working. It gives me this error:

> `getCurrentPosition()` and `watchPosition()` no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See  for more details.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Your amazon instance should be https

Comment: get a `SSL certificate` for your site, if you are not able to purchase one then have a look at https://letsencrypt.org/, they provide free SSL certificates

Answer (score 0):

This happened due to using not-secured URL, so as a workaround you can use 
[Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro)
,then you can register and send Geolocation requests using POST to the following URL:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key={{ 
 registerd_Key}}"
```